# Netbeans, phpdocumentor, and custom phpdoc.dist.xml by project

Tags: netbeans, phpdoc

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 and phpdocumentor 2.8.2 on a windows 7 platform.

I would like to use custom `phpdoc.dist.xml` config files by project so I can specify framework directories and etc. to exclude from the generated doc. I also want to keep my Netbeans PHPDOC plugin config as generic as possible, without specific output directories, ignore options, config path parameters, etc., so on, so that that the config will apply to all my projects.

The `phpdoc.dist.xml` file works great. The doc generated is exactly what I want.

The problem or feature, and it seems to be a phpdocumentor one as it also applies from plain command line, is that the `phpdoc.bat` command (without a specific config parm) has to be run from the same root directory as the `phpdoc.dist.xml` file, or it ignores it. No problem if I'm using command line as I can change into that directory first, but I would like to use Netbeans. I have searched on this extensively and cannot find an answer.

I considered whether to modify the `phpdocumentor` files to insert `cd /D path/to/myproject/dir` to change the directory using some Netbeans variable to represent `myproject/dir`, but I could not find the right place in the code or the variable to use. Plus, then I'm supporting a custom mod to `phpdocumentor`.

I did find [these directions for a PHPStorm setup](http://kevinquillen.com/ide/2015/02/01/setting-up-phpdocumentor-in-phpstorm-8/), where the author specified a PHPStorm variable for the `--config` command line option to point to his custom `phpdoc.dist.xml`.

```
--config="$ProjectFileDir$/phpdoc.dist.xml"
```

If I could do the same in Netbeans like maybe `"${BASE_DIR}/phpdoc.dist.xml"` it would be great, but so far I haven't hit on anything Netbeans will recognize/pay attention to in the PhpDoc script: box.

I have also tried writing a wrapper `.bat` file to capture my own command line variable `%1` and do the directory change to that before calling `phpdoc.bat`, but Netbeans throws and error and says that's not a valid `.bat` file. I cannot find any `phpdocumentor` parameter to configure by specific Netbeans project but the output directory. And I would prefer not to be defining a bunch of projects on subdirectories in Netbeans, just to address `phpdocumentor`.

Now I am out of ideas. Can anyone point me to a solution?